# How do I desaturate a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

Is there an easy way (or a built-in library) in iOS 5.x to desaturate a UIImage? Here's currently how I am doing it:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height); // flip image right side up
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.image.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSaturation);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, self.bounds, image.CGImage); // restricts drawing to within alpha channel
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, desaturation);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context); // restore state to reset blend mode
```

This seems to be a bit more complicated than I expected. Is there a simpler way than this?

I was thinking of Core Image, but I can't seem to find a concrete example on how to do desaturate an image using that.

Comment: Not sure, but possibly you could try applying [CIFilter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of [kCICategoryColorEffect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCICategoryColorEffect) type. Quick demo how to apply CIFilter: http://iazapps.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/applying-cifilter-on-image-in-an-uiimageview/

Comment: what is your value for desaturation???

Comment: indiekiduk, that code appears in more context in an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144768/how-can-i-change-the-saturation-of-an-uiimage (desaturation is an ivar in the example).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework using two or three lines of code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inputimage.png"];    
GPUImageGrayscaleFilter *grayscaleFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];
UIImage *grayscaleImage = [grayscaleFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

(remembering to release the filter if not building using ARC)

This reduces the image to its luminance values, desaturating it. If you want variable saturation / desaturation, you can use a GPUImageSaturationFilter. As the framework name indicates, this filtering runs on the GPU, and is faster than Core Image in almost every situation I've benchmarked on iOS as of 5.1.

Comment: Brad is there a way to re-saturate the image with original colours after desaturating it? Currently it seems like a one-way trip when you desaturate an image using GPUImage. Is keep a copy of the original image the only solution? I was hoping for a more Photoshop like non-destructive saturation adjustment layer :P

Comment: @Zhang - No, if you want the original colored image you need to keep that around, because information is lost in the desaturation. You can have multiple targets for your images and filters, though, so you can split off a second processing path before you perform a desaturation. Photoshop's nondestructive filters keep around copies of the original image to work from.

Comment: Sorry to hijack the comments but Brad, I discovered a weird behaviour when using this gray scale filter on an iPad vs simulator. I have an array of "colored photos". I declared a grayscale filter outside the for loop. Inside the for loop, I used the grayscale filter and converted each color photo to a grayscale image, then added to my other NSMutableArray. The result when displayed in a table view is that all row uses the same photo. If I declare the Grayscale filter inside the for loop, then it shows correct photo. I am using ARC. Seems like grayscale filter has some sort of cache mechanism.

Comment: @Zhang - If you are using the `-prepareForImageCapture` or `-imageByFilteringImage:` methods when grabbing these filtered stills, an optimized download routine using the texture caches is employed. This does a direct memory mapping between the filter output and the UIImage generated from this, so if you keep that UIImage around, the filter will be locked to that image and any other images you create will share the original's memory mapping. You need to either not use the faster image processing path or convert the UIImage to another form and use that for your persistent thumbnails.

Comment: Hi Brad, Your code works great, but i get memory warning on this code. My project using ARC. Here is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406403/gpuimage-grayscale-and-contarst-filter-generating-memory-warning